# Update keys in nested dictionary with some exception in key strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I've a list of students which looks something like this :

```
students = [ {'name': 'Jack' , 'status' : 'Average' , 'subjects' : { 'subject1' : 'English' , 'subject2' : 'Math' } , 'height' : '20cm' },
{'name': 'Tom' , 'status' : 'Good' , 'subjects' : { 'subject1' : 'English' , 'subject2' : 'Science' } , 'height' : '30cm' }
 ]
```

So the above list is of size 2. Assume that the size is pretty big, lets say 50 or 60 or more.

I want to return a **list** students_output & for each student I want to return a dictionary which contains the following values for each student which are fetched from the above list but have slightly modified 'keys'. The end output should be something like this :

```
students_output = [ {'student_name': 'Jack' , 'student_status' : 'Average' , 'student_subjects' : { 'student_subject1' : 'English' , 'student_subject2' : 'Math' } , 'child_height' : '20cm' },
{'student_name': 'Tom' , 'student_status' : 'Good' , 'student_subjects' : { 'student_subject1' : 'English' , 'student_subject2' : 'Science' } , 'child_height' : '30cm' }
 ]
```

I am not able to understand how I can create an effective loop so that the keys in my resultant data structure are maintained as provided in the output and i can fetch the data from the first list.

for example, in students_output, I know

```
students_output[0]['student_name']=students[0]['name']
```

But can anyone help me do it iteratively ?

Comment: What do you mean by "effective loop so that the keys in my resultant data structure are maintained as provided in the output"?

Comment: You need to show what you've already tried

Comment: So you wanna prefix each key with student, and suffix each subject's key with the count? Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: but you also want to prefix `height` with `child_`?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't get past "Assume that the size is pretty big, lets say 50 or 60 or more.", because it's too funny.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you have to concatenate `"student_"` at the start of each key with some exception as `"height"` key. You may do it via combination of *list comprehension* and *dict comprehension* expression as:

```
students = [ 
    {'name': 'Jack' , 'status' : 'Average' , 'subjects' : { 'subject1' : 'English' , 'subject2' : 'Math' } , 'height' : '20cm' },
    {'name': 'Tom' , 'status' : 'Good' , 'subjects' : { 'subject1' : 'English' , 'subject2' : 'Science' } , 'height' : '30cm' }
]

def get_key(key):
    return {
       'height': 'child_height',  # All exception you need in `key`
                                  # apart from concatenating `"student_"`
       }.get(key, 'student_' + key)

new_list = [{
    get_key(k): ({
         get_key(kk):v  for kk, vv in v.items()} if isinstance(v, dict) else v) \
             for k, v in s.items()
    } for s in students]
```

Value hold by `new_list` will be:

```
[{'student_name': 'Jack', 'child_height': '20cm', 'student_status': 'Average', 'student_subjects': {'student_subject1': {'subject1': 'English', 'subject2': 'Math'}, 'student_subject2': {'subject1': 'English', 'subject2': 'Math'}}}, 
 {'student_name': 'Tom', 'child_height': '30cm', 'student_status': 'Good', 'student_subjects': {'student_subject1': {'subject1': 'English', 'subject2': 'Science'}, 'student_subject2': {'subject1': 'English', 'subject2': 'Science'}}}]
```

Comment: it's probably a micro-optimization, but I would make the dictionary in `get_key` a default-named argument. Then, it is only parsed once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty function that will do what you need:

```
In [10]: def rename_keys(students):
    ...:     d = {}
    ...:     for k,v in students.items():
    ...:         if isinstance(v,dict):
    ...:             k = "student_" + k
    ...:             v = rename_keys(v)
    ...:             d[k] = v
    ...:         elif k == 'height':
    ...:             k = "child_height"
    ...:             d[k] = v
    ...:         else:
    ...:             k = "student_" + k
    ...:             d[k] = v
    ...:     return d
    ...:
    ...:

In [11]: [rename_keys(d) for d in students]
Out[11]:
[{'child_height': '20cm',
  'student_name': 'Jack',
  'student_status': 'Average',
  'student_subjects': {'student_subject1': 'English',
   'student_subject2': 'Math'}},
 {'child_height': '30cm',
  'student_name': 'Tom',
  'student_status': 'Good',
  'student_subjects': {'student_subject1': 'English',
   'student_subject2': 'Science'}}]
```

And really, this doesn't have to be recursive, you could substitute the recursive call with a dictionary comprehension:

```
v = {'student_'+key:value for key,value in v.items()}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following function inside a list comprehension like this:

```
def new_dict(d):
    res = {}
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        student_or_child = 'student' if key != 'height' else 'child'
        if type(value) == dict:
            res['{}_{}'.format(student_or_child, key)] = new_dict(value)
        else:
            res['{}_{}'.format(student_or_child, key)] = value
    return res
```

The above function takes a dict as argument, for each `key, value` in the passed `dict`, if value is of type dict then the same function is called on value, and the result is added to `res` dict, else the same value is added.

Now, with a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), we can do:

```
[new_dict(d) for d in students]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [new_dict(d) for d in students]
[{'child_height': '20cm', 'student_name': 'Jack', 'student_status': 'Average', 'student_subjects': {'student_subject1': 'English', 'student_subject2': 'Math'}}, {'child_height': '30cm', 'student_name': 'Tom', 'student_status': 'Good', 'student_subjects': {'student_subject1': 'English', 'student_subject2': 'Science'}}]
```